# Dataloader Capabilities

Tags: data-loader

I will be using dataloader for an extraction in Salesforce . I havn't used Salesforce so please bear with my naive questions .

1. Is it possible to take extraction of a Master object and it's related child by performing some kind of join or do I need to take that exxtraction separately for each object?
2. I have been provided a table list where the field names donot look like API names . Something like Party char / create . Are those internel field names in SFDC ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You need to do separate queries for each object, even if there is a relationship field linking them.
2. You can build a mapping from your other names to salesforce api names that you can reuse on data loads when inserting/updating records, but ultimately need the api names.